# Get JSON from localhost API with https

Tags: angular, typescript, api, .net-6.0, webapi

I want to read some json data from a simple API (WebAPI, NET6, just 1 Controller) in Angular.

But if I try to get the data from the localhost api url, I get an "UnknownError" response (no status code).

Performing a GET via the browser or Postman I see the correct JSON response. Am I missing something on the Angular side (but it looks simple as all examples) or do I have to configure something on the API side to work on localhost (https?) outside the browser?

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
...

export class CurrentValuesService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient, ...) { }

   ...

   getSomething() {

      let bla = this.http.get('https://localhost:7228/api/CurrentData/LastValue').subscribe(
        (x) => {
            console.log(x);
        },
        (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        }
        );
   }
}
```

Comment: Probably CORS. You need to allow the origin that you use for the angular app.

Comment: provide error you got, please

Comment: It was a CORS - error. Adding CORS in the startup of the WebAPI solved the problem